# Como exibir duas tabelas diferentes do banco de dados em php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Ola pessoal é o seguinte, eu tenho 2 tabelas distintas, e não dá para fazer inner join, pois elas não possuem nenhum dado em comum, eu queria saber se é posivel exibir essas duas tabelas em uma unica página.

Comment: sim, com duas consultas e exibição separadas uma abaixo da outra... (tenho uma loja virtual que chega a 155 consultas ao DB em uma única pagina, e tudo isso em 0,385ms)

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela1
CROSS JOIN tabela2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola, outra idéia é utilizar UNION, mais as tabelas devem ter a mesma estrutura e a mesma quantidade de colunas, exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   table2
```

ou

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.nome
FROM   table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, t2.nome
FROM   table2 t2
```